# Tensorflow how to make a training data

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a begginer in programming I beg your pardon for that question, I just want to learn.

The function

```
tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

returns

```
Tuple of Numpy arrays: (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test).
```

But I want a data set like this (x,y) with $x$ a data and $y$ a label. So this is my attempt :

```
import tensorflow as tf
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
N = np.size(x_train)

training_data = []
for i in range(N):
    training_data.append( (x_train[i], y_train[i]) )

n = np.size(x_test)
test_data =  np.zeros( (n,2) )
for i in range(n):
    test_data[i] = (X_test[i],y_test[i])


net = Network([784, 30, 10])
net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

And the error I get which i don't understand :

> ```
> training_data.append( (x_train[i], y_train[i]) ) IndexError: index 60000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 60000
> ```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve with loops can be quickly done via the following:

```
train_data = np.array(list(zip(x_train, y_train)))
test_data = np.array(list(zip(x_test, y_test)))
```

Also, note that `np.size` gives you the *overall* number of elements (floating points) inside the multi-dimensional array, i.e. here $60K\times28\times28$, so you run out of indices.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to wait some hours to wait if someone can explain me why I messed up then I'll give you the accept :).

Comment: it’s in my last paragraph, you messed up because you used np.size, instead you need to use x_train.shape[0] and you’ve other errors in your test loop as well

Comment: Oh okay, x_train is a array of 60Kx28x28 so... If I want to get the 60 I need to do x_train.shape[0]. Good thanks you once again.